# Objective-c and c++ on linux

Tags: objective-c

I have some maybe stupid question. What is the difference between C++ and objectice-c. Is there IDE for objective-c for linux ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to expand a bit on DaVinci's point 1.

First the similarities:

Objective-C  and C++ were both originally based on C.  Both languages support an object oriented model.  That's where the similarities end.

Objective-C is a strict superset of C, C++ is not.  Any C program is also an Objective-C program.  This is not necessarily the case with C++.

The syntax of Objective-C's OO extensions is closer to the syntax of Smalltalk than that of C whereas the reverse is the case with C++.

The philosophies behind the OO models is completely different too.  Objective-C's model is dynamic in the spirit of Smalltalk.  C++'s model is more static.  With Objective-C, you send messages to objects and the object decides at run time how it is going to respond to the message.  With C++ the methods that an object responds to - even the virtual ones - are defined at compile time.  This makes Objective-C's object model immensely more powerful than C++'s object model.  For instance, you can add whole sets of new methods to existing classes without using inheritance.  You can even replace method implementations on the fly.

This all comes at a cost of course.  Sending messages to Objective-C objects is quite a bit slower than calling C++ virtual functions.  However, I think the benefits are worth the cost and you can always drop back to C for performance critical sections of code.

NB there is also a language called Objective-C++ which is the Objective-C OO extensions built on top of C++ instead of C.

Comment: are you sure Obj-C++ is OO extensions on top of C++?  I was under the impression that it compiled to C, and then compiled into the C++ program.  Which now that I type it out, seems silly.

Comment: but you can't mix object-calls in ObjC++, right?  The OO aspects are completely separate?

Comment: C++ objects are totally different from Objective-C(++) objects but that doeasn't mean you can't use both kinds in an Objective-C++ source file.

Answer (score 0):

1. they are simply two quite different languages.
2. I think gnustep is the only objective-C environment/library, it also has a IDE: project center, however Objective-Cs home is primarily on Apple products.